# SSRS 2008 - Report Sorting as Parent & Child and Children in Alphabetical Order

Tags: sorting, ssrs-2008, sql-server-2008

I have a 'List' element in my report for which data is taken from 'Dataset1'. Dataset1's SQL query is

`SELECT SNo.,Name,TreeStructurePath
 FROM dbo.SampleTable
 WHERE ....
 *ORDER BY TreeStructurePath*`

Output:

```
SNo.    Name         TreeStructurePath
0       Root         .
1       Austin       .A001
2       Wesley       .A001.B001
3       Ronald       .A001.B001.G003
4       Claire       .A001.B001.M005
5       Dolbie       .A001.C001
6       Belle        .D001
```

This data is displayed in the above order as it is sorted by 'TreeStructurePath' field. But my requirement is following output in my report.

```
SNo.    Name         TreeStructurePath
0       Root         .
1       Austin       .A001
2       Dolbie       .A001.C001
3       Wesley       .A001.B001
4       Claire       .A001.B001.M005
5       Ronald       .A001.B001.G003
6       Belle        .D001
```

Here, '.' is Root. A001, D001 are Child Groups of '.'. B001 and C001 are A001's children. B001 has two child G005,M005. These are sorted in SQL query. But in my report requirement is Parent Group(Root) should be on the top but their children should be sorted in alphabetical order(A001-B001 [G003,M005] then C001; D001). Is that possible? If so, how to achieve that in SSRS 2008 reoport?

I dont care whether 'TreeStructurePath' is in alphabetical order or not. I want 'Name' in alphabetical order i.e.,

```
Root
   ----A001 (Root child - Austin)
    --------C001 (A's child - Dolbie)
    --------B001 (A's child - Wesley)
                ------------M003 (B's child - Claire)
                ------------G005 (B's child - Ronald)
   ----D001 (Root child - Belle)
```

(Ignore indentation)
I am using 'TreeStructurePath' to list chidren below their parents. If I dont use that chidren will be listed somewhere but not below their parents.Hope you got what I am asking.

PS: If not for 'List' item, please suggest solution for a 'Tablix' (containing 3 fields).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the Report Query, you can do something along these lines to parse out each grouping of your treestructurepath so you can sort in the report table or data result.

```
   SELECT SNo ,Name, TreeStructurePath, 
            SUBSTRING(TreeStructurePath, 2, 4) AS Tree1,
            SUBSTRING(TreeStructurePath, 7, 4) AS Tree2, 
            SUBSTRING(TreeStructurePath, 12, 4) AS Tree3
      FROM dbo.SampleTable
           WHERE ....
       Order by Tree1 ASC, Tree2 ASC, Tree3 DESC
```